# Variable not working in shell script

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have a source code :

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH=Test/bin/
java -cp ${CLASSPATH} "test.shell.com.RunTest"
```

That code return the error with content as bellow : Error: main class test.shell.com.RunTest could not be found or could not be loaded

But when I change it to :

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp Test/bin/ "test.shell.com.RunTest"
```

It return the correct result of RunTest class. 
I try change CLASSPATH to other name but it still error. Please help.

Comment: have you tried without the curled braces?

Comment: What happens if you replace `java` with `echo` in your original script?

Comment: @LukeK it same problem without {}

Comment: @Chrs it return without CLASSPATH when echo. Result : `test.shell.com.RunTest` I dont know why it not undestand CLASSPATH

Comment: How are you running this script? It looks like it should be fine

Comment: @Chrs I runned it via cygwin. I dont know what is the reason?

Comment: It would help to show the terminal commands you are running and the output

Comment: @Chrs this is link image terminal [https://ibb.co/kEeJmQ](Image). The message is japanese languages, english content it is "main class test.shell.com.RunTest could not be found or could not be loaded"